# How to reproduse spinner behavior for view

Tags: android, view, spinner, z-order

I want to place my view in front of everything on the layout. My view is in ListView item and I want it to be in front of another ListView Item. What I want is my view to be like popup from image below, it is from first item but it is shown in front of other items.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvQtZ.png)

Comment: What did you do? what is your view. is your view IN your ListView or ON your listView? You will have downvotes...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question. But maybe this will help:

1 - If you are using android studio, in the design tab, try to move your view to the bottom. It will put it on top of the other views.

2 - Try to play with with your view's elevation property. If you set it to 2, I think it will do the trick.

However I would suggest you to give more details, so people can help you. 
Maybe some, image, xml...

Comment: I have the view in ListView item and I want it to be  in front of another ListView Item.